If the projection angle of a vector on an axis is alpha, can we call the projection of the vector as the ''projection through the angle alpha''?
When we project a vector F on an axis, if the angle between this vector and its projection is equal to alpha, Can we call the projection vector as the projection of the original vector through the angle alpha? (In other words, is the use of through correct in this context?)

Edit: I post the original text here. The author has used the word ''through'' there. As you mentioned, it suggests that we are rotating the vector F by angle alpha not projecting it on the axis x.
This is the part of the textbook in question :

In this section, we saw that we can define a force in space by its
magnitude and direction or by the three rectangular components Fx, Fy,
and Fz. A. When a force is defined by its magnitude and direction, you
can find its rectangular components Fx, Fy, and Fz as follows.
Case 1.
If the direction of the force F is defined by the angles θy and φ
shown in Fig. 2.25 [I have attached the image below], projections of F through these angles
will yield the components of F. Note that to
find the x and z components of F, first project F onto the horizontal
plane; the projection Fh obtained in this way is then resolved into
the components Fx and Fz



What has 'through' to do with it? You are projecting the vector onto the x-axis. It's not going 'through alpha' but is the x-component of F. If you bring 'through alpha' into it, it suggests you are rotating the vector by angle alpha, which would have the same length. Please show an example sentence which you want to use.

I don't think this is a question about English, but about mathematical terminology. Most English speakers won't understand what you're talking about.

I’m voting to close this question because it's a highly technical domain-specific usage that means nothing to me. Nor would it mean anything to most native speakers, as has been pointed out.

I don't think the question has been asked very clearly. The diagram is not labeled clearly.  Are we talking about two vectors, F and F-prime?

My question is very simple and does not require much math knowledge. The vector F is projected onto the x-axis. The projection of F on the x-axis is represented by the vector Proj F and it is assumed that the angle between F and its image Proj F is alpha. Now the question is, can we say that ProjF is the image of F on the x-axis through the alpha angle?This question came to me while reading a mechanics book. The name of the book is Vector Mechanics for Engineers written by Beer and Johnston. This book is very famous and I have the 11th edition of it.

indeed, I simplified the form of the question. In fact, in the text of the book, a three-dimensional vector is depicted on the coordinate axes. I put the image of the relevant page here (and what is needed to understand it)

I was wondering why such a famous writer who is a native English speaker would make this mistake.

Perhaps someone with the geometry knowledge will be able to answer this well, but with my limited understanding, it seems to me that the textbook is reasonable and the only reason it can't be used as you propose is not a misunderstanding of language but of the geometric operations. Personally I see no reason why this question should be closed, but I doubt the specialized knowledge to answer it will come along.

The usage is not correct. The writer has confused the process of resolving the vector into its components with the process of defining the axes.
When we resolve vectors, we talk of projecting the vector onto another vector or onto a defined set of axes. We don't talk of rotating the vector "through" an angle. That's a different operation.
